# Handling async data with rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

I have a loginComponent that receives an email and a password and makes an http request to get the user data. After that, I want to use that user data in other components using a service.

login component:

```
  onRecievingResults(value:loginInterface){
    this.authService.saveData(value);
  }

  onLog(){
    this.onRecievingResults(this.loginUser)
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/stats/list')
  }
```

The service:

```
  public currentUser:User | null = null;

private dataUserSource = new BehaviorSubject<User | null>(this.currentUser);
  dataEmitter = this.dataUserSource.asObservable();

  public saveData(value:loginInterface){
    this.loginUser(value).subscribe()
    this.dataUserSource.next(this.currentUser);
  }

  public loginUser(loginInterface: loginInterface | null){
    const url = `${this.basicURL}/login`
    const body = {email: loginInterface?.email, password1: loginInterface?.password1}
    return this.http.post<loginResponse>(url, body)
    .pipe(
      map(({user, token}) => this.setAuthentication(token, user)),
    catchError(err => throwError(() => err.error.message))
    )
  }

  private setAuthentication( token:string, user: User){
    this.currentState = authStatus.Authenticated
    this.currentUser = user
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
    console.log(this.currentUser) //<-- Here i have the userData
    return true
  }
```

My other service:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.dataEmitter.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
  }

  public currentUser:User | null = null
```

The problem is that in the component I want to use the User data after login the app I have "null", but in the method that I use in my service to update that data, I can get the User data. what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `saveData(): Observable<void> { return this.loginUser(value).pipe(map(_ => this.currentUser)).subscribe(this.dataUserSource); }` and then `onRecievingResults(value:loginInterface) { return this.authService.saveData(value); }` and then `onLog(){ this.onRecievingResults(this.loginUser).pipe(concatMap(_ => this.router.navigateByUrl('/stats/list')).subscribe(); }`

Comment: I think the answer of @Bastian Bräu is correct. I would just put it in this way `this.loginUser(value).subscribe(this.dataUserSource)`. In this way you can brodcast not only values notified, but also error and complete signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscription is asynchronous, so the `next()` on your Subject will be called before `this.currentUser` is updated.

So, you could just emit the Subject inside of the subscription.

```
public saveData(value:loginInterface){
    this.loginUser(value).subscribe(() =>
        this.dataUserSource.next(this.currentUser)
    );
}
```

Also, it would be more clear if you moved the contents of the `map()` function inside the subscription.